# How to answer whatsapp audio calls with bluetooth headset?

Tags: telephony, whatsapp-messenger

I'm trying to use a headset based on Bluetooth to answer whatsapp calls, but even when I can answer normal calls, it wont work on the headset.

Is there a option to enable it on android phones?

Comment: I use it without any issues. First try with another BT set. They're isn't anything to be done on Android side